# Is there a difference if I don't define a Primary Key in a table

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I've been using SQL Server for quite a while, I always create database with design view.

The steps I took to create the table is:

- Right Click Table -> New Table
- I always have the first column as `SOMETHING_ID` (int) -> I make `SOMETHING_ID` as `Identity` with auto increment of 1
- -> Then I add other columns
- -> Save and use

As you can see, I didn't define `SOMETHING_ID` by right clicking it and SET AS PRIMARY.

Will there be any performance impact in this case?

Comment: DON'T SHOUT, difference not different, and don't put tags in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can impact performance because creating the primary key essentially makes an index for it.  So when you join tables on that key it will improve performance greatly if there are indexes.... particularly if you have lots of data.

Answer (score 2):

What you really need to do is to create a clustered index. A primary index, by default is a clustered index (but you can create a primary index that is not a clustered index). A table without a clustered index is called a heap and except for very special occasions you should have a clustered index on every table.  A primary index is a index that has only unique values and does not have any (not even one) null index value.

A query that uses a clustered index is usually a very effective one but if there is not clustered index (even if the table has indexes) it can end up with forwarding pointers all over the place and searching for all the rows for a given customer can require SQL Server to read many, many pages.

To create a clustered index on a table you can use syntax such as

```
create clustered index ix1_table1 on  table1(id)
```

The column(s) used in a index of any kind can occur anywhere in a table and does not necessarily have to be identity columns.

Comment: Instead of using syntax to create one, it's the same if I right click the field and set it as primary key right?

Comment: Yes. SSMS will generate TSQL code to create the primary index.

Answer (score 1):

By not creating Primary key you're breaking the rule of First Normal Form in Normalization.

Disadvantages of not having Primary Key

1. Chances of Duplicates
2. Your table won't be clustered with clustered index
3. You won't be able to do Primary Key-Foreign Key relationship with other table.